# Permission Denied for Kubernetes Secrets with SELINUX Enabled

Tags: kubernetes, app-secret

I followed kubernetes documentation to manage secrets of my applications.

http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/secrets.html

When pod starts it kubernetes mounts secret at the right place, but application is unable to read secret data as it described in documentation.

```
root@quoter-controller-whw7k:/etc/quoter# whoami
root
root@quoter-controller-whw7k:/etc/quoter# ls -l
ls: cannot access local.py: Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? local.py
root@quoter-controller-whw7k:/etc/quoter# cat local.py 
cat: local.py: Permission denied
```

What is wrong with that?

---

SELinux configured with enforcing mode

`SELINUX=enforcing`

Docker started with the following command

```
/usr/bin/docker daemon --registry-mirror=http://mirror.internal:5000 --selinux-enabled --insecure-registry registry.internal:5555 --storage-driver devicemapper --storage-opt dm.fs=xfs --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/atomicos-docker--pool --bip=10.16.16.1/24 --mtu=8951
```

Comment: IIRC there are some issues with SELinux and Secrets such as https://github.com/projectatomic/adb-atomic-developer-bundle/issues/117 which you could try out

Comment: Thank you Michael, my issue related with SELinux as it described in github issue page.

Comment: Good. Let me turn that then in a proper answer. Would appreciate if you could upvote/mark as correct so that others after you benefit from it as well.

Comment: Eduard, can you verify which OS variant you're using?  Are you using ADB?

Comment: Paul, I am using Amazon AMI for CentOS Atomic Host 7.20151118

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known issue with SELinux and Kubernetes Secrets as per the Atomic issue tracker, see [ISSUE-117](https://github.com/projectatomic/adb-atomic-developer-bundle/issues/117).